# $stateChangeSuccess not working with localforage in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement user authentication with ui-router but not able to do.

Having header.html and HeaderController for showing menu bar or login.html and loginController for login functionality then have other page user.html after login I want to show menu when user is on user.html page,

Process first as user login the  LoginController will user service and set localforage with accesstoken and redirect to user.html. in between on header controller I am using $stateChangeSuccess to check if the user is loggedIn from localforage accessToken and if the accessToken is there I checked the isLoggedIn flag to true which is on header.html to show the menu bar. But at first time I am not seeing any menu after login need refresh to see the menu there.

service.

```
    loginUser : function(user) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : configurations.API_URL + '/auth ',
            data : angular.toJson(user),
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
        }).success(function(data) {
            if (data && data.access_token) {
                fstorage.setItem('accessToken', data.access_token, '').then(function(data) {

                }, function(error) {

                });
            }
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function(error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    },
```

on headerController.

```
    $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function($event, current) {
        $scope.isLoggedIn = false;
        var pathname = "action-pending";
        if ($state) { ;
            pathname = $state.url().replace('/', '');
        }
        $scope.selectedMenu = pathname;
        fstorage.getItem('accessToken').then(function(data) {
            if (data) {
                $scope.isLoggedIn = true;
            }
        }, function(error) {

        });

    });
```

on header.html for showing menu.
using  ng-if="isloggedIn" to show or hide menu

So can any one help where at I am wrong.

Comment: Can you edit a part of your code ?

Comment: Are you sure the "isloggedIn" in the same scope is used?

Comment: @D_S_toowhite yes I am using the isLoggedIn in the same controller scope html.